# Highcharts summing results that have same date

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have installed Highcharts on my web site, but I have a problem. MySQL returns data in that value:

```
['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['11.03.2013', 1], ['21.03.2013', 1], ['22.03.2013', 1]
```

And it is included in Highcharts like that:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Statistika prenosov'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text:'Datum'
        }
    },
    yAxis:{
        title: {
            text:'Prenosi'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },


   series: [{
            name: 'Prenosi',
            data: [['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['26.03.2013', 1], ['11.03.2013', 1], ['21.03.2013', 1], ['22.03.2013', 1]]
        }]
    });

});
```

But I want, if there are three dates 26.3.2013, then don't show them for each alone, but put them together, so result should be 3, not 3x1.

Here is, how I fetch results with PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE prjID='".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY date ASC");
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);
$res='';
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$i++;
$date=date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['date']));

$numb=1;

if($i!=$num){
$res.="['".$date."', ".$numb."], ";
}
else{
$res.="['".$date."', ".$numb."]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to modify your SQL to sum it for you. If you are trying to display the count of each date, then change your query to:

```
SELECT date,count(*) as num FROM downloads WHERE prjID='".$_GET['id']."' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC"
```